# Create a flag for consecutive value of column

Tags: r

I am trying to get the count of quantities where there are consecutive zeros in the quantity column grouped by brand,area,date using R. How do i get the count?

I have tried rle , rleid functions, but couldn't get to the solutions

Actual data sample:

```
structure(list(Brand = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("B1", "B2"), class = "factor"), 
        Area = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
        2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("A1", "A2"), class = "factor"), 
        Date = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
        4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L), .Label = c("4/1/2019", "4/2/2019", "4/3/2019", 
        "4/4/2019", "4/5/2019", "4/6/2019", "4/7/2019", "4/8/2019"
        ), class = "factor"), QTY = c(345L, 3455L, 34L, 23L, 0L, 
        0L, 677L, 883L, 383L, 43L, 3L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("Brand", 
    "Area", "Date", "QTY"), row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = c("data.table", 
    "data.frame"))
```

Desired output
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFdXj.png)

Thanks

Comment: Please don't provide images of data. Provide the data sample itself using `dput()`. Also, can you describe how you attempted to use rle and why it didn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way of getting your desired output is this:

```
require(dplyr)
data %>% group_by(Brand, Area) %>%
  mutate(flag=ifelse(QTY==0 & (lag(QTY)==0 | lead(QTY)==0),1,0),
    zcount=ifelse(QTY==0,sum(flag),NA))
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 15 x 6
# Groups:   Brand, Area [2]
   Brand Area  Date       QTY  flag zcount
   <fct> <fct> <fct>    <int> <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 B1    A1    4/1/2019   345     0     NA
 2 B1    A1    4/2/2019  3455     0     NA
 3 B1    A1    4/3/2019    34     0     NA
 4 B1    A1    4/4/2019    23     0     NA
 5 B1    A1    4/5/2019     0     1      2
 6 B1    A1    4/6/2019     0     1      2
 7 B1    A1    4/8/2019   677     0     NA
 8 B2    A2    4/1/2019   883     0     NA
 9 B2    A2    4/2/2019   383     0     NA
10 B2    A2    4/3/2019    43     0     NA
11 B2    A2    4/4/2019     3     0     NA
12 B2    A2    4/5/2019     4     0     NA
13 B2    A2    4/6/2019     0     1      3
14 B2    A2    4/7/2019     0     1      3
15 B2    A2    4/8/2019     0     1      3
```

Comment: is there a way to count the '1' occurred in the flag column and place them in new column for that particular group.

Comment: See the revised answer above.

Comment: data %>% group_by(Brand, Area) %>%
  mutate(flag=ifelse(QTY==0 & (lag(QTY)==0 | lead(QTY)==0),1,0))%>% summarize(zeros=sum(flag)). this is what you meant? I have edited the desired output, if you can provide in that format it will be helpful

Comment: Yes. I added the expected output for it. Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: no, i am looking for output similar to the one in "Desired output" image

Comment: I have the solution 
setDT(df)
df[ , count_zero := sum(flag == 1 & QTY==0|QTY==0), by = .(BRAND,AREA)]

Comment: That's conflating data.tables with the tidyverse, which is a bit much for such a simple task. You can probably achieve this whole thing with just DT, but I'm less familiar with the package.

Comment: Just to close the loop on this, I revised my solution to address your new desired output within the tidyverse.